# How to fix jest snapshot errors due to ng-reflect inconsistently printing same moment as GMT+0 vs GMT-0

Tags: angular, jestjs, momentjs

I have an Angular Component that takes a Moment.moment object as an Input and some higher-level Jest Snapshot tests that cover that component.

When I run the snapshot tests locally, all is good but in the Jenkins CI environment it complains:

```
    -         ng-reflect-date="Mon Jul 22 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0"
    +         ng-reflect-date="Mon Jul 22 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0"
```

As you can see, the only difference is which offset format was used when angular reflected its inputs to the DOM.

What is causing this inconsistency and is there a way to standardize it across environments?

Comment: do you [set default timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/) in your tests? I'd expect this solve inconsistency.

Comment: @skyboyer setting/changing the default timezone has no effect on the output here.  GMT is not actually the default timezone nor is it the current timezone of this moment object.

Comment: does it happen for any datetime value? or just for `moment()`-based values? just trying to guess, snapshot worked well to me with date stringified by default timezone I mocked. did you try testing snapshot with smallest possible component? or does it happen for any of your component expected date input?

Comment: @skyboyer Great question.  I don't have a large body of data here but so far it seems to happen exclusively and consistently with moments.  Dates seem to print consistently across environments, moments inconsistently.

Comment: found issue with "-00" and "+00". It's quite old but I'm not sure what version do you use so take a look https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/194 Maybe it makes sense to file bugreport in momentjs' bugtracker

Comment: Yeah it's a similar issue to that.  I think the problem is related to the locale definition being different for some reason (Linux vs Mac?).  In any case, this seems like a reasonable workaround for my tests:

```
    moment.fn.toString = function toString() {
      return this.format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]');
    };
```
as suggested here: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1018#issuecomment-24568040

Comment: please make it an answer for your own question. it might help somebody with similar issue

Answer (score 0):

[Update: REPLACED INCORRECT ANSWER]

Angular's ng-reflect truncates the string output after 30 characters which in this case results in a complete-looking, but actually-incomplete, timestamp.

So the snapshot test was tripping over the timezone difference between the local env and the test env.  This didn't affect the *visible* output in my case because the component displays the value in a set timezone, but it *does* affect the input moment and thus the ng-reflect and snapshot.

In my instance, the solution was to explicitly set the timezone for the test as originally suggested by @skyboyer.  At first this appeared not to have an effect because the difference was truncated by ng-reflect. But with this change, and once the snapshot was updated, it consistently matched in all environments.

Comment: @skyboyer if you put your suggestion as an answer, i'll mark it accepted and move the above story into a comment instead.